# Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php

Hi I am trying to make a members only website, I've trying to create a script with sessions etc however when I click my login button I get the following error:

`Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0`

`Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'prepend.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php') in Unknown on line 0`

I'm not 100% sure what this all means, so I'll post my script and would appreciate if somebody could tell me in depth where I'm going wrong so I can grasp and learn for the future what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance for any input and help.

index.php

```
<div id="maincontentWrapper">
<div id="maincontent">
    <div id="contentWrapper"></div><!--End loginWrapper -->
        <article>
            <p>Welcome to iManage, please login in below.</p>
        </article>
    <div id="loginform">
        <div id="loginWrapper">
        <form id="loginForm" method="POST" action="classes/class.Login.php">
        <h1><span class="log-in">Log in</span> or <span class="sign-up"><a href="register">sign up</a></span></h1>
        <div id="errorDiv"><?php 
                    if (isset($_SESSION['error']) & isset($_SESSION['formAttempt'])) {
                            unset($_SESSION['formAttempt']);
                            print "Errors encountered<br/>\n";
                            foreach ($_SESSION['error'] as $error) {
                            print $error . "<br />\n";
                        } //end foreach
                        } //end if 
                ?></div>
    <p class="float">
        <label for="login"><i class="icon-user"></i>Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
          <span class="errorFeedback errorSpan" id="emailError">E-mail is required</span>
    </p>
    <p class="float">
        <label for="password"><i class="icon-lock"></i>Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="showpassword"> 
                <span class="errorFeedback errorSpan" id="passwordError">Password is required</span>

    </p>
    <p class="clearfix"> 
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log in"></form>
    </p>   
        </div>

    </div>


</div>
</div>

</div>
```

classes/class.Login.php

```
<?php 
include("../connect/class.Connect.php");

class Login extends Database {

    public $id;
    public $email;
    public $username;

        public function __construct() {
            if (session_id() == "") {
                session_start();    
            }
            if (isset($_SESSION['isLoggedIn']) && $_SESSION['isLoggedIn'] == true) {
                $this->_initUser();     
            }

        } // end construct

        public function authenticate($user, $pass) {

            $safeUser = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($pass);
            $query = "SELECT * from users WHERE email = '{$safeUser}'";

                if (!$result = $this->mysqli->query($query)) {
                        error_log("Cannot retrieve account for {$user}");
                        return false;
                }   

                // will be only one row, so no while() loop needed
                $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
                $dbPassword = $row['password'];

                if (crypt($incomingPassword,$dbPassword) != $dbPassword) {
                        error_log("Passwords for {$user} don't match");
                        return false;
                }
                    $this->id = $row['id'];
                    $this->username = $row['username'];
                    $this->email = $row['email'];
                    $this->isLoggedIn = true;

                    $this->_setSession();
                    return true;    
        } // end function autheticate


        private function _setSession() {

            if (session_id() == '') {
                session_start();    
            }

            $_SESSION['id'] = $this->id;
            $_SESSION['email'] = $this->email;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $this->username;
            $_SESSION['isLoggedIn'] = $this->isLoggedIn;

        } // end function setSession

        private function _initUser() {

            if(session_id() == '') {
                sessions_start();           
            }

            $_SESSION['id'] = $this->id;
            $_SESSION['email'] = $this->email;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $this->username;
            $_SESSION['isLoggedIn'] = $this->isLoggedIn;



        }// end function initUser

        function validatelogin () {
                    $_SESSION['formAttempt'] = true;

        if (isset($_SESSION['error'])) {
        unset($_SESSION['error']);
        }

         $_SESSION['error'] = array();

        $required = array("email","password");

            //Check required fields
            foreach ($required as $requiredField) {
            if (!isset($_POST[$requiredField]) || $_POST[$requiredField] == "") {
            $_SESSION['error'][] = $requiredField . " is required.";
            }
            }


            if (!filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $_SESSION['error'][] = "Invalid e-mail address";
            }

            if (count($_SESSION['error']) > 0) {
                die(header("Location: login.php")); 
            } else {
                $user = new User;
                if ($user->authenciate($_POST['email'], $_POST['password'])) {
                    unset($_SESSION['formAttempt']);    
                 die(header("Location: authenticated.php"));
            }else {
                 $_SESSION['error'][] = "There was a  problem with your username or password.";
                 die(header("Location: login.php"));
                }
        }
        }



}

$run = new Login();
    $run->authenticate($user, $pass);
    $run->validatelogin();
?>
```

prepend.php

```
<?php

if (!isset($_SESSION) ) {
session_start();    
}
?>
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
php_value auto_prepend_file "prepend.php"
```

Comment: Is `include("connect/class.Connect.php");` a valid path?

Comment: @RienNeVaPlus sorry originally I had it going back one directory `../connect/class.Connect.php`, it didn't make a difference, usually if it can't find the database it would output a different message

Comment: When you try to run some PHP script, PHP tries to include file "prepend.php" because of .htaccess.

What are folders of .htaccess, prepend.php and your script?

Comment: .htaccess and prephend.php are in a directory up from classes/class.Login.php, would these need to be in the same root directory? or can I give the classes folder a .htaccess? @Sanja

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set absolute path to prepend.php in .htaccess

Comment: thanks sanja that worked! got a few errors on the script but I should be able to solve those ones.

Comment: Note that you might need the absolute system path even if your webspace is otherwise heavily `chroot`-ed. Hard to debug.

Answer (score 6):

My antivirus software likes to put the router.php in quarantine (effectively removing it from that directory). Check if yours did the same and if so restore it and create an exception for that file. Additionally you should configure your antivirus to notify you if it puts something in quarantine, so you can intervene in time.

Comment: yep that was it, my avast in silence mode was deleting my server.php, thank you ^^

Comment: I had this problem with Avast Antivirus, I checked the quarantine vault and it was there my php file.

Answer (score 3):

This error come due to missing of server.php .Same happen with me. You check server.php file in your project directory.

Answer (score 1):

It's one of the causes under the  **auto_prepend_file** and **waf file** missing or corrupted.
So, please check the php.ini or .user.ini file on your webroot and remove or recorrect the file path.

Answer (score 0):

If added antivirus software, add an exception or remove the antivirus software. There might be a chance of removal of the file (server.php) from the project folder. Check whether the file is available.