# PHP Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required | public duplicate in index.php link

Tags: php, fatal-error, zend-framework3

My project use Zend 3 framework and php7.2. When I build web on Ubuntu 17.04, this web isn’t working.

```
> php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t public public/index.php
[Thu Dec  7 23:25:59 2017] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[Thu Dec  7 23:25:59 2017] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/home/isling/workspace/sp/shopping/public/public/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in Unknown on line 0
```

'.../public/public/index.php' -> public is duplicated ???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18674298/warning-unknown-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory-in-unknown-on)

Comment: You specified the home directory as `public` and requested `public/index.php`, which results in `public/public/index.php`. Use `/index.php` instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `-t` argument specifies the document root, it is assumed that's where the indicated file is. So you just need this:

```
php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t public index.php
```

I usually put this in my `composer.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "serve": "php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t public/ index.php"
}
```

Then I can just do `composer serve` to get a development server.

**[EDIT 2018-04-27]** This behavior has changed around version 7.2.3 or so. The filename parameter now appears to be relative to the current directory and not relative to the doc root directory specfied via `-t`, so you'd now use something like: `php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t public/ public/index.php`

Answer (score 3):

This error is generally thrown when `-t` or `public` is missing from the command. @Alex correctly explains the reason behind it.
first, navigate to your project directory and then enter this from the command line.

```
php -S localhost:<your port number> -t public
```

[check this link on how to run php built-in web server from command line](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)

Answer (score -1):

I have face same issue, Deactivate your antivirus software for a hour. Try copy pasting check `server.php` is exist in your folder or not